# Flash messaging is being named incorrectly when using bootstrap and simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm not sure why this is happening, but when I submit a form successfully in my rails app it is adding a div class of an error to my successful flash message. I'm using this code for my flash messages:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
   <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

That's exactly what Ryan Bates suggests doing in this rails cast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/329-more-on-twitter-bootstrap?view=asciicast

What is wrong with that code? It works fine if I simply do this:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name %>">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But that doesn't seem to be the right way to do this. I don't understand why the code suggested in the railscast doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may put a string `'notice'` instead of a symbol `:notice` when you created the flash message in your controller.  Try adding these lines in your `application.html.haml` to see what you get from your flash messages

```
- if Rails.env.development?
  = debug(params) 
  = debug(flash) unless flash.empty?
```

Comment: I added that debug message and it's showing this: https://skitch.com/leemcalilly/eu4dn/the-fuzz-cloud

Comment: Your `flash` contains `:success` but not `:notice`, so change your code to `:success ? "success" : "error"`

Comment: I think this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, `flash` sometimes contain empty elements. Check if you have something in `flash` before iteration.

Comment: Checking to see if the flash is empty first doesn't help because the flash isn't empty, it is just sending adding the alert-error class to the div